# Coloring DC.JS Choropleth Charts

Tags: d3.js, graph, dc.js, choropleth, graph-coloring

Trying to color a DC.JS choropleth chart. The Default colorAccessor isn't working and I am at a loss for making things work. Any help would be tremendous. I feel like some custom reduce function is necessary but I am not too sure how or where.

http://codepen.io/MichaelArledge/pen/vLKZzE?editors=001

```
      chart.width(c_w)
                .height(c_h)
                .dimension(zip_code_dim)
                .group(zip_totals)
                .projection(projection)
                .colorAccessor(function(d){ console.log(d);  return d.value;  })
                .overlayGeoJson(statesJson.features ,"zip_area");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not defining the overlayGeoJson function from where to get the value

You defined like this:

```
overlayGeoJson(statesJson.features ,"zip_area");
```

Should have been

```
 .overlayGeoJson(statesJson.features ,"zip_area", 
function(d){ return d.properties.zip})
```

Now b'coz the above function returns zip codes so `d.value` will be `undefined`

```
.colorAccessor(function(d){ return d.value;  })
```

It should be

```
 .colorAccessor(function (d) { return colors(d); });
```

I have defined a linear scale for colors its value should be returned from colorAccessor function.

```
  var colors = d3.scale.linear().range(["#E2F2FF", "#C4E4FF", "#9ED2FF", "#81C5FF", "#6BBAFF", "#51AEFF", "#36A2FF", "#1E96FF", "#0089FF", "#0061B5"]);
```

Full working code [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMXvPJ?editors=001)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you so much. Reread the documenation over and over and that concept never clicked. Thank you.